# Django remove image based on id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

Suppose I have the following simple model:

```
class GraphData(models.Model):
    """
    Stores graph data for easy access
    """
    uid = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column='uid')
    graph_params = models.TextField(db_column='graph_params')
```

I want to delete image which is located at `server.com/images/<uid>.png`, when row in database is deleted.
I know that I need to catch `pre_delete` signal, but how to delete the image itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, configure your [`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#media-root):

```
import os


# Project root is intended to be used when building paths,
# e.g. ``os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'relative/path')``.
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))

# Absolute path to the directory that will hold uploaded files.
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'uploads/')
```

Then you can use [`os.remove()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
import os

from django.conf import settings


def delete_file(path):
    """
    Deletes specified file from uploads.

    Usage:
        delete_file('path/to/file.extension')
    """
    os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path))
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to do that would be to use os.remove which we use in python.

Ex: `os.remove(path)`

where path is the file path